# How to create relationship between three tables in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, crud, entity-relationship

I have to create relationship between 3 tables in Laravel. Can anybody tell me which is the best way to create Entity Relationship?

Model Client.php

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $table = "clients";
    protected $fillable = ['id','name','surname','company','address','tel','email','businessnumber'];
    
}
```

Model Service.php

```
class Service extends Model
{
    protected $table = "services";
    protected $fillable = ['id','name','price'];
}
```

Model Invoice.php

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    protected $table = "invoices";
    protected $fillable = ['id','client_id','invoicenumber','duration','mwst','rabatt','total','invoiceDate','dueDate','comment','status'];

}
```

So, these are my Models and now what kind of Entity Relationship do I have to use in models and what I have to change in my tables.

Expected result:
1 Invoice has many Serivces and 1 Client. For example:

```
#0020-19 John Doe  service1 99$   2 Month = 198$
                   -----------------------------
                   service2 199$  2 Month = 398$
                                    ------------
                                     mwst  = 20$
                                    ------------
                          discount(rabatt)  = 5$
                        ________________________
                                    total = 611$
```

## I am using Validator for inserting data.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship should be as follow:

1. `Client` - hasMany -> `Service`
2. `Service` - belongsTo -> `Client`
3. `Service` - belongsTo -> `Invoice`
4. `Client` - hasMany -> `Invoice`
5. `Invoice` - belongsTo -> `Client`
6. `Invoice` - belongsTo -> `Service`

**Edited:**

Make sure you have these fields and table exists.

1. `services` must have `client_id` & `invoice_id`
2. `invoices` must have `client_id`

**Edited 2:**

As invoicing process comes after services... in such case you should create a separate table for the relationship b/w `Service` -belongsToMany-> `Invoice` And same in `Invoice` model as well `Invoice`-belongsToMay-> `Service`.

The field changes would be as below:

1. `services` must have `client_id` & `invoice_id`
2. `invoices` must have `client_id`
3. there should be intermediate table like `services_invoices` that contains the `id`, `service_id` and `invoice_id`.

Comment: Hopefully you are able to define this in code! Let me know if you not.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand the relationship that you have described, I'll try to define this in code. Is there any mistake in my tables or I have to continue like that?

Comment: Added required fields in solution.

Comment: I saw the Edited 2 and I have created a pivot table called `services_invoices`. How can I add data into pivot table and invoice table in the same time in this case. So, remember I have to create an invoice with multiple services and they should be have a relationship between them.

Comment: You can use `attach()` check the documentation.